# What is the correct name of this compound?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

> What is the correct name of this compound?
>
> [image]
>
> **1**. 2-Chloro-5-isopropoxy hexane;
>   **2**. 2-Chloro-5-(1-methyl ethoxy)hexane;
>   **3**. 5-Chloro-2-isopropyl hexane;
>   **4**. 5-Chloro-2-(methyl ethoxy)hexane.

Isopropyl or methyl ethoxy. Which one is correct?

Comment: Both are correct, but only one is _systematic_.

Comment: Please see our [guidelines on how to ask nomenclature questions](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/3066/).

Comment: Strictly speaking, the answer should be ‘none of these’ since all proposed names include unnecessary spaces. Anyway, this question seems to be based on obsolete IUPAC recommendations from 1993 since ‘isopropyl’ is no longer a preferred prefix in the current recommendations from 2013.

Answer (score 1):

[image]The answer is 5-chloro-2-isopropoxy hexane. When you write an IUPAC name of the compound, you need to write the substituents’ names in alphabetical order I.e., C comes first, hence 5-chloro should be written first and then follows I, hence -2- isopropoxy comes next. This is the IUPAC(systemic) name.
The common name is 5-chloro hexyl isopropyl ether

[image]

【EDIT: The group encircled has been wrongly mentioned as isopropoxy group. It's isopropyl group. But the encircled part along with the O forms the isopropoxy group. 
[Note: I am not the original answerer of the question.]】

[image]

Answer (score -4):

The correct answer is **D**.

First of all, you have to know that numbering in this compound starts from the carbon, which is nearly connected to ether, so accordingly you find $\ce{Cl}$ is at 5th position.

Now, according to your doubt how you think that it is isopropyl. It must be either isopropoxy or methyl ethoxy. So, in the following option there is only methyl ethoxy is present, holding all the rules of IUPAC nomenclature it is the correct answer.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. Please see our [guidelines on how to answer nomenclature questions](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/3066/). Please back up your explanations with corresponding citations of the rules your have used. I believe the name should be 2-chloro-5-isopropoxyhexane, according to alphabetic ordering and lowest set of locants.